# Dynamically change color of segments of a jQuery UI slider bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a horizontal jQuery UI slider bar, and I want to dynamically change the color of multiple segments of that bar to indicate that something is special about these segments of the slider. Ideally, the color would also extend below the bar, so it can be seen even when the slider handle is on top of a colored segment.

I don't know how to approach this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is make a slider div, and then embed divs into there, with each one having a different background-color (using CSS). Then to dynamically change the colors of these, all you have to do is change the css of each div using `$("#id").css("backgroundColor", "color");`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6NcvL/1/

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
<input id="value" value="0" readonly />
```

CSS

```
#slider {
    height: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
#red {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
#green {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
#blue {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
#value {
    padding-top: 30px;
    border: 0;
}
```

JQuery

```
$("#slider").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $( "#value" ).val( ui.value );
    }
});
```

Comment: Tip: To make this look better, you can round out the end divs. Example: border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;